# Find $\int \sin x \cos (\cos x) \cos(\sin x)+\cos x\sin(\cos x)\sin(\sin x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How do I find: $$\int \sin x \cos (\cos x) \cos(\sin x)+\cos x\sin(\cos x)\sin(\sin x)dx$$? I made this one up by taking the derivative of $-\sin (\cos x)\cos (\sin x)$, and I wonder how someone would solve this monster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, split the integral:$$\int\sin x\cos (\sin x)\cos(\cos x)dx+\int\cos x\sin(\cos x)\sin(\sin x)dx$$Apply integration by parts to the first integral (where $\cos(\sin x)$ is $f$ and $\sin x\cos(\cos x)$ is $g'$): $$-\sin(\cos x)\cos (\sin x)-\int\cos x\sin(\cos x)\sin(\sin x)dx+\int\cos x\sin(\cos x)\sin(\sin x)dx$$Cancelling we get the answer. This was a very pretty solution.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \sin x \cos (\cos x) \cos (\sin x)= & -\int \cos (\sin x) d(\sin (\cos x))\\=& -\cos (\sin x) \sin (\cos x)-\int \sin (\cos x) \sin (\sin x) \cos x d x \quad \textrm{ (By IBP)}
\end{aligned}
$$
Removing the last integral to the left yields
$$\int \left(\sin x \cos (\cos x) \cos (\sin x)+\cos x \sin (\cos x) \sin (\sin x) \right)dx= -\cos(\sin x) \sin (\cos x)+C
$$